# How can the following result of casting from float to numeric be explained?

Tags: sql-server, casting, floating-point

```
DECLARE @f AS FLOAT = '29545428.022495';
SELECT CAST(@f AS NUMERIC(28, 14)) AS value;
```

---

```
29545428.02249500200000
```

Today I've read this example. I understand the problem of floating point numbers but do not understand the result of this casting. How it works?

### UPDATE

First, we can replace varchar in the first line, the result will be the same.

```
DECLARE @f AS FLOAT = 29545428.022495;
```

Second, I think the problem is in casting. Try the following code.

```
DECLARE @f AS FLOAT = 29545428.022495;
select @f - 29545428;
```

---

```
0,0224950015544891
```

Maybe it is the reason of `002` in the end.
It works with other numbers.

### UPDATE 2

OK, I think I understand it in a wrong way. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005725/save-float-values-in-sql-server)'s a related question and the answer.

Comment: `VARCHAR -> FLOAT (innaccurate datatype) -> NUMERIC (exact datatype)` With first implicit casting you get precision error. Read also [Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: What is 0.022495 as a sum of powers of 2?

Comment: @lad2025 at first I thought the same. Then I've selected f. It is 29545428,022495

Comment: @doctorlove I don't understand the sense of your question.